# How to evaluate $\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\rvert_0 ((\rho^t_X)_{*}Y)$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$,$Y$ be smooth left invariant vector fields on a Lie group $G$. Let $\rho^t_X: G \rightarrow G$ the diffeomorphism along the flow of $X$ at time $t$. So I want to evaluate this derivative with respect to $t$.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\rvert_{t=0} ((\rho^t_X)_{*}Y)_{\rho^t_X(e)}$$

I know there is a formula relating the bracket with the pushforward, namely:

$$[X,Y]_p = -\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\rvert_{t=0} ((\rho^t_X)_{*}Y)_p.$$

So if instead of $\rho^t_X(e)$, I get a fixed point $p$, the $2$ formulas will be the same. I am tempted to say the derivative will evaluate to $[X,Y]_e$ by plugging in $t=0$. However, as $\rho^t_X(e)$ changes with time $t$, I do not even know if the derivative exists or not. Can someone explain whether the derivative exists, and if it does, what does it evaluate to?

Comment: No, what you've written does not make sense. You cannot subtract tangent vectors at different points. Because you have a Lie group, you can of course move the tangent vector at $\rho_X^t(e)$ back to $e$ by (the derivative of) left multiplication; but, as it stands, not defined.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought. I got to this by doing a problem so I must have made a mistake somewhere along the way. Thanks.